# Cannot get the describe information for the calling stored procedure

Tags: database, db2, db2-zos, ibm-data-studio

I am trying to call a DB2 stored procedure from a java application and getting the error below:
`Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][10453][12711][4.22.29] Cannot get the describe information for the calling stored procedure with name XXXXXXXX and path ' SYSIBM , SYSFUN , SYSPROC , SYSIBMADM , WSTCFS1 ' ERRORCODE=-4472, SQLSTATE=null`

I found the [explanation and solution](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/PI47282) (search- ERRORCODE=-4472) of this error but doesn't makes much sense.

And this is the version of driver I am using:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Calling the same stored procedure from IBM Data Studio works fine though.

Comment: Your exact driver version is omitted from your question (regardless of what is in the POM file),  what matters is __all__ the text that comes before the "Cannot get the describe information...", i.e. starting from "com.ibm..." and including all the numbers at the end.  Also you should specify in your question how you run the java app (i.e. standalone, or via some app server) because most likely the driver that __it__ is using is downlevel. DataStudio comes with its own driver which is why that works.

Comment: Driver version 4.22.29 is as per POM file and supposedly contains the fix, but apparently does not.  Try changing the pom file to specify version 11.5.8.0 (which is the currently available driver), and retry, and then edit the question with the new result. Please don't use comments to add facts that should instead be in the question, because comments are not searchable.

Comment: I believe my organization doesn't have any existing repo that points to latest version of driver. Therefore, I manually downloaded the latest db2jcc4.jar (4.32.28 version) and used it locally but still getting the same error. `Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][10453][12711][4.32.28] Cannot get the describe information for the calling stored procedure with name XXXXX and path ' SYSIBM , SYSFUN , SYSPROC , SYSIBMADM , WSTCFS1 ' ERRORCODE=-4472, SQLSTATE=null` Am I missing something else?

Comment: So it's not the driver. What is the difference between the way you run the SQL in DataStudio versus in your App?  Literals? Named-Parameters? Have you taken a jdbc trace to see what is happening under the covers?  Did you open a ticket with IBM Db2-support (all z/os customers can do this).

Comment: Thanks @mao for your effort here. Yeah looks like its not the driver issue and now reaching out to db people within my organization to take a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have both `db2jcc4.jar` and `db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar` in the classpath for the connection. In addition the user/password for the table schema you want to access has to be granted.

You can find both files under the Unix System Services in the z/OS image where Db2 is installed. No need to have a repo and the files much match the Db2 version you are going to access, that’s why you need to contact your DBA.

With Data Studio you can access because either the Db2 Connect license is installed in your computer or the jdbc access has been set up with the proper files and classpath, as described in the previous paragraph.